# Limit debug logs from external crates

Tags: rust, rust-tracing

I'm trying to limit debug logs from other crates. This is how I'm init logging

```
    let subscriber = tracing_subscriber::fmt::Subscriber::builder()
        .with_max_level(args.log_level)
        .finish();
    tracing::subscriber::set_global_default(subscriber)?;
```

Comment: Limit to what? Do you mean omit them?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Limit/omit